# How to translate get_intermediate_image_sizes?

Tags: images, translation, localization

I use the following code to get image sizes:

```
public function getImageSizes(){
        global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
        $sizes = array();
        foreach(get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s){
            $sizes[$s] = array(0, 0);
            if( in_array( $s, array( 'thumbnail', 'medium', 'large' ) ) ){
                $sizes[$s][0] = get_option( $s . '_size_w' );
                $sizes[$s][1] = get_option( $s . '_size_h' );
            } else {
                if ( isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) && isset( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $s ] ) )
                    $sizes[$s] = array( $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width'], $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height'] );
            }
        }
        return $sizes;
    }
```

The result is a select with image sizes, something like this:

```
<option value="thumbnail">Thumbnail</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="large">Large</option>
<option value="tribe_image_widget_custom" selected='selected'>Custom</option>
```

The question is how to translate sizes (Thumbnail, Medium, Large and Custom)? By default the sizes are in English, I need them to be another language (I use CodeStyling Localization plugin for it).

Thank you!

P.S.: to biuld a select I use this code:

```
<select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('size'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('size'); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($this->getImageSizes() as $name => $atts): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $name ?>"<?php echo ($name==$size?' selected':'') ?>><?php echo ucwords($name) . ' ('. implode( 'x', $atts ). ')' ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `$sizes` is an array containing the image sizes; how do you build the select options?

Comment: Sven, thank you for your help. I use the following code to build a select:

Comment: `<select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('size'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('size'); ?>">
    <?php foreach ($this->getImageSizes() as $name => $atts): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $name ?>"<?php echo ($name==$size?' selected':'') ?>><?php echo ucwords($name) . ' ('. implode( 'x', $atts ). ')' ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>`

Comment: I also posted this code above (in the question) with better formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [__(), _e(), _x() or _ex()](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/) and your textdomain to make your theme or plugin translatable.

I stripped your code snippet to the basics, so you will get the idea more easily:

```
<select class="widefat">
  <?php foreach ( $this->getImageSizes() as $name => $atts ) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $name; ?>" ?>>
      <?php echo ucwords( __( $name, 'textdomain' ) ); ?>
    </option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Unfortunately internationalization is not possible with variables like `$name` so you will have to provide the default image size names to make them accessible:

```
$sizes = array(
  __( 'thumbnail', 'textdomain' ),
  __( 'medium', 'textdomain' ),
  __( 'large', 'textdomain' )
);
```

If you're adding the image sizes yourself you can avoid the hack above if adding them like this:

```
add_image_size( __( 'custom-image-size', 'textdomain' ), $width, $height, $crop );
```

Comment: Oh, now I see! Sven, thank you a lot for your kind help!

Comment: @Ksenia You're welcome! Please accept the answer to mark this question as solved :)

Comment: Done! Sorry, this is my first question on Stack Exchange :)